# populate combobox with WMI query using C#

Tags: c#, combobox, wmi

Can someone help me with this problem.I'm trying to populate combobox with the value from WMI query. But I don't know how to do it. Googled to find the solution but to no avail.

```
private void Form_Load1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ManagementScope oScope = new ManagementScope("\\root\\cimv2");
    ObjectQuery oQuery = new ObjectQuery("select DisplayName from Win32_Service");
    ManagementObjectSearcher oSearcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(oScope, oQuery);
    ManagementObjectCollection oCol = oSearcher.Get();


          foreach (ManagementObject col in oCol)
          {
              String displayName = col["DisplayName"].ToString();

              comboBox1.Items.Add(displayName);


          }
```

I change to foreach loop but it displays all the properties value. How to choose 'DisplayName' instead? Thanks

Comment: Why you added this code in the `comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged` event ?

Comment: try to bind values from select query to combobox...

Comment: This code will work only if you there is a selection change in the combo. Try placing this code in Form Load event or create a method an invoke the method from Form Load

Comment: Not working.Compiled but without result that I'm looking for